# How to write my first app using chocolatechipui?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, chocolatechip-ui

I am trying to use chocolatechip ui for my project, i have never developed anything for a mobile before. I went through the documentation, installed and built all the demos. There is absolutely no section on how to build your first app, is there any blog or resource I can use for the same ?

On a side note, is there any other mobile-web frame work that i can use for my project, that has good documentation and smaller learning curve.I dont want to do native app development

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice, easy to follow ChocolateChip-UI Book on GitHub that teaches all you need to know in order to start creating your first app [here](https://github.com/sourcebits-robertbiggs/ChocolateChip-UI-Book/blob/master/10-Your%20First%20App.markdown).

In order to build a hybrid app, you can either follow their instructions to [manually generate the packaged app for each platform](https://github.com/sourcebits-robertbiggs/ChocolateChip-UI-Book/blob/master/18-Making%20Hybrid%20Apps.markdown), or use [Apache Cordova or Phonegap](https://github.com/sourcebits-robertbiggs/ChocolateChip-UI-Book/blob/master/09-integration.markdown#phonegap) to wrap your mobile Web app with native code so that your Web app becomes a 'native' app.

I'm developing a hybrid app using ChocolateChip-UI, Cordova and AngularJS, and the results are very good so far. I'll probably create a generic project structure with those technologies together and publish the source on GitHub soon.